# FAR-manager replacement for FTP

Tags: ftp, midnight-commander

I'm trying to get rid of Windows and now I have Ubuntu 17.10 on my second PC but I'm beginner in Linux. Everyday I need to work a lot with FTP (uploading/downloading files). Now I'm trying to find something like FAR-manager (Windows only).

Why it is so important? I want to do **all the actions with keyboard only**, without any need to touch the mouse. When I try to connect with Midnight Commander via "FTP link" menu, error appears: "ftpfs: Login incorrect for user anonymous". Filezilla works with mouse only so it's not a option for me.

What application would you recommend to use for FTP uploads/downloads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Midnight Commander will suite your needs as it needs terminal and provides FTP-client with dual/twin panels as FAR.

But it has one limitation which is serious nowadays. It does not support FTPS (FTP over SSL). There is a [3 year-old bug](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3343) about that.

For plain FTP you can use `Left` (or `Right`) and `FTP Link` with the following syntax (from F1 help):

```
┌───────────────────────────── Help ─────────────────────────────┐
│FTP File System                                                 │
│                                                                │
│The FTP File System (ftpfs) allows you to manipulate files on   │
│remote machines. To actually use it, you can use the FTP link   │
│item in the menu or directly change your current directory      │
│using the cd command to a path name that looks like this:       │
│                                                                │
│ftp://[!][user[:pass]@]machine[:port][remote-dir]               │
│                                                                │
│The user, port and remote-dir elements are optional. If you     │
│specify the user element, the Midnight Commander will login to  │
│the remote machine as that user, otherwise it will use          │
│anonymous login or the login name from the ~/.netrc file. The   │
│optional pass element is the password used for the connection.  │
│Using the password in the VFS directory name is not             │
│recommended, because it can appear on the screen in clear text  │
│and can be saved to the directory history.                      │
│                                                                │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

For SFTP (FTP over SSH) you should use `SFTP link` with syntax:

```
┌───────────────────────────── Help ─────────────────────────────┐
│SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) filesystem                    │
│                                                                │
│The SFTP file system is a network based file system that allows │
│you to manipulate the files in a remote machine as if they were │
│local.                                                          │
│                                                                │
│To connect to a remote machine, you just need to chdir into a   │
│special directory which name is in the following format:        │
│                                                                │
│sftp://[user@]machine:[port]/[remote-dir]                       │
│                                                                │
│The user, port and remote-dir elements are optional. If you     │
│specify the user element, the Midnight Commander will try to    │
│login on the remote machine as that user, otherwise it will use │
│your login name. port - specify the port used by remote server  │
│(22 by default). If the remote-dir element is present, your     │
│current directory on the remote machine will be set to this     │
│one.                                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

On GUI session you can try [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/) (clone of Total Commander), it is installable with `sudo apt-get install doublecmd`. It has FTP/FTPS and SFTP client, accessed from `Network->FTP`.

Comment: If my answer helped, you may vote for it and then accept it. It's how "thank you" on AskUbuntu works :)

Comment: I would like but my reputation is too low to vote up for now. I need 15 but my score is only 6 for now. Clicking upvote doesn't work for me.

Comment: OK, no problem :)